# Effect of x = +x in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Going though the [asm.js](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/) documentation I've observed this strange (to me at least, quite new to JS) snippet all over the sample code:

```
function test(x) {
    x = +x; // THIS
    ...
    return +(x*y);
}
```

What is the purpose of the `+` on the first line?

Comment: might be changing it to a number...!

Comment: `typeof '3'` => "string"
`typeof +'3'` => "number"

Comment: The `+` in the `return +(x*y);` is redundant, actually

Comment: @adrianp Well, that's a little different. The reason it's redundant in your original code is because `*` coerces them to perform the calculation, so the result of the `()` is `NaN` or a `Number`. In this new example, as long as the result of `sqrt` is a `Number`, then it is still redundant. If `sqrt` produces (or can produce) a `String`, then it's "necessary" to convert with `+` in this case

Comment: @adrianp it performs a number cast. If you want an int cast, do `|0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I am reading this wrong but from the specs http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/#parameter-type-annotations

is that casting it as a double?

Comment: Yes, I missed that. Interesting to see how `int` and `double` casting is done differently.

Comment: No, it doesn't cast it specifically as a "double". To do that, you use `parseFloat`, and `parseInt` (for "integers"). Using `+` converts it to a `Number`. So if it's "int"-looking, it converts it to an "int". If it's "float"-looking, it converts it to a "double".

Answer (score 6):

Its simply used for `casting` a value with another type to number. Additonally it will return `NaN` if the value after that `+` symbol could not get converted into a `number`.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FStMy/)**

**From the book Javascript and Jquery - The Missing Maunal**

```
var numOfShoes = '2';
var numOfSocks = 4;
var totalItems = +numOfShoes + numOfSocks;
```

Adding a + sign before a variable (make sure there’s no space between the two) tells
the JavaScript interpreter to try to convert the string to a number value—if the string
only contains numbers like “2”, you’ll end up with the string converted to a number.
In this example, you end up with 6 (2 + 4). Another technique is to use the Number()
command like this:

```
var numOfShoes = '2';
var numOfSocks = 4;
var totalItems = Number(numOfShoes) + numOfSocks;
```

Number() converts a string to a number if possible. (If the string is just letters and not
numbers, you get the NaN value to indicate that you can’t turn letters into a number.)